# node js ENOENT error

Tags: node.js

running this code giving me this error, trying to fig out since an hour but failed

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var port = 3010;

http.createServer(function(req, res){
    var query = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
    console.log(query);
    var file = query.f + query.t;
    //var file = "eurusd_m1.json";  
    console.log(file);
    var eurusd;
    fs.readFile('data/' + file + '_m1.json', function(err,data){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        }           
        eurusd = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(eurusd);
    });
    res.writeHead(200,{'content-type':'text/plain'});
    res.end("helllo owrld");    
}).listen(port);

console.log("server running at port 3010..");
```

it's giving me below result:

---

```
server running at port 3010..
{ f: 'eur', t: 'usd' }
eurusd
{}
NaN
{ [Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\zeromq\data\NaN_m1.json']
  errno: 34,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\zeromq\\data\\NaN_m1.json' }

undefined:1
undefined
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
    at Object.parse (native)
    at C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\zeromq\dataserver.js:17:17
    at fs.js:207:20
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

---

Comment: `NaN_m1.json`. That's not your filename is it? The `var file = query.f + query.t` is evaluating to `NaN` which is probably not what you want. Print `query` to see if it holds the values you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is the client's request to `favicon.ico`. There are *two* requests being performed here (hence, you see the log twice). The browser asks for the page *and* for the favicon.ico file representing the tiny little icon you see when you bookmark and to the left of the address bar :)

Your problem is in `var file = query.f + query.t;` - this makes sense when you access the page, but does not make sense when accessing favicon.ico implicitly by your browser.

You are just `console.log`ing the error instead of returning from it, which means you JSON.parse on an undefined value - which throws a syntax error as defined in the spec (just try opening the console and typing JSON.parse(window.x) in your browser)

(You can see this by the ENOENT when it tries to open `"NaN_m1.json"`)

You can add this to your server before calling `url.parse`, but if you intend to make it bigger - proper routing is probably better:

```
if (req.url === '/favicon.ico') {
    r.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon'} );
    return r.end();
}
```

Comment: thanks Benjamin for a quick response, but how come its NaN, i can see it before giving it to readFile in console.log that it's spitting eurusd, then why it's taking it as NaN. how should i correct it any idea.

Comment: @zishan try `console.log(req.url)` on top - see what URLs are being accessed. There are _two_ requests being sent by the browser and not one (hence the double logging for the rest). Detect if the url matches the route you want and act accordingly :)

Comment: @zishan the NaN you're seeing is `undefined+undefined` by the way - which is the query parameters for `favicon.ico` . If I may suggest an introductory book, I've found nodebeginner.org quite useful.

Comment: thanks Benjamin for th enodebeginer,I already read few pages and order soon, it a nice to have book. here is my req.url console.log -> /?f=eur&t=usd and here is the url i am passing http://localhost:3010/?f=eur&t=usd

Comment: @zishan if this has resolved your issue, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), if it has not - please consider elaborating on why. Thanks and happy coding :)

Comment: benjamin your code helped and i got rid of the error now, can actually see the json +10 to you, now what should i have to do if i will have to tell node server not to do any request for favicon, is there any config file where i can do this instead of telling node in my program.